# UITableViewCell text alignment center

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "ChatCell")

    // put the data
    cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    cell.textLabel!.textAlignment = .Right
    cell.textLabel!.text = array[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

I'm creating and using default `UITableViewCell` with `textAlignment`. Right, but it doesn't work.

By the way, Red color works well.

My environment is `iOS9` with `swift`.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "ChatCell")
```

instead of

```
let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "ChatCell")
```

Comment: 1. What 'Value1' means?
2. Can I use Subtitle after applying No.1?

Comment: It's different style of default table view cell.

Comment: Also try with .Default .

Comment: OK. Let me try it.

Comment: Sooner you will also. All we are leaning here.